# Как вывести PictureBox на печать?

Tags: c#, печать, picturebox

Есть такой pictureBox:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Его надо вывести на печать. Пробую так

```
 private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog()) {
            using (PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument())
            {
                document.PrintPage += Doc_PrintPage;
                dialog.Document = document;
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) document.Print();
            }
        }

    }

    private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(graphicsPB.Width, graphicsPB.Height);
        graphicsPB.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, graphicsPB.Width, graphicsPB.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
        bitmap.Dispose();
    }
```

Но выводится просто серый экран.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рисую на PictureBox через `Graphics g = PictureBox.CreateGraphics();` в методе по нажатию на кнопку "рисовать"

Выяснилось, что после нажатия на кнопку печати, печати в файл и сворачивания и разворачивания окна, все что нарисовано на PictureBox пропадает. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Потому что PictureBox предназначен не для рисования в CreateGraphics, а для показа изображений. А если уж рисуете вручную, то надо это делать в обработчике Paint, и брать Graphics из его аргументов. Вы определитесь, про что у вас вопрос в итоге, вывод на печать или отрисовку?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Отрисовывает все корректно, не печатает.

Comment: Никогда, никогда не используйте `CreateGraphics` у контролов! Как вам уже сказали, рисовать нужно в событии `Paint`. Просто перенесите код отрисовки туда. В качестве объекта отрисовки используйте `e.Graphics`.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код печати работает, если PictureBox использовать по назначению - установить у него свойство ImageLocation для отображения картинки. Если вы рисуете на него своим собственным кодом, DrawToBitmap не работает, да и он не нужен: это лишнее растровое преобразование и возможная потеря качества. Просто рисуйте на объекте Graphics из PrintPageEventArgs то же самое, что вы рисуете на PictureBox, результат будет идентичен.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал загрузить в PictureBox Bitmap (или Metafile) и рисовать на нём. Так можно будет рисовать в большем разрешении, чем позволяет размер PictureBox, чтобы улучшить качество изображения при печати.